# How to share information is user logged in between Next js and CRA from same backend if jwt token is stored as session cookie in header response

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, proxy, create-react-app

We're building two different applications which operate under same domain, and are hosted in different servers.

First application is in Next js and contains all pages available before login.

Second application is in Create React app and contains all info available only after user is logged in.

Login and all backend routes are handled on separate express server. After successful login jwt token is stored in session cookie, and in all requests to backend from CRA app jwt token is automatically added in headers.

So in first application next js, user can be logged in or simple guest, but depending of that we need to show different headers. This is the part where I don't have clear understanding how to retrieve info is user logged in or not.

I made proxy in next js

```
 async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/user",
        destination: "https://someurl/api/auth/user/", // Proxy to  Backend
      },
      {
        source: "/logout",
        destination: "https://someurl/api/auth/user/logout", // Proxy to  Backend
      },
      
    ];
  }
```

So when I'm logged in CRA localhost and I start Next js server when I manually go to http://localhost:3000/user I have information of current user whether he is logged in or not, on the other hand if I make this same request through getServerSideProps backend returns me that I'm logged out.
I suppose this is the issue unique session id, but since I can't see this api request in Network tab I have no idea what is happening.

I would appreciate any thoughts and idea how to share information about login between these two applications if jwt is stored in session cookie as response from backend

Comment: Can you please confirm if the JWT token cookie's domain is set to the base domain (e.g., example.com), so it can be accessed by both the Next.js and CRA applications? What I am trying to say is that, will the next app have access to the cookie set by CRA app?